# Unable to fetch row elements values using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I'm little new to Javascript.

This is using django as backend.

I'm trying to capture data from table columns like 'dose', 'duration' and 'usage' which uses text box and checkbox.

Whenever I hit the button with id='qty', then I'm able to see correct value for first click but when I click the button for another element it still submits same previous data instead of data on the same row.

Below is the sample output that I captured from console log

```
#Item 1 Log
[Log] Object (e28c8d12-1a95-44e5-9813-dfc2f4bf3bb1, line 502)
code: ""
dose: "1"
name: "PARACIP"
price: undefined
quantity: "2"
total: NaN
usage: {morning: false, afternoon: false, evening: false, night: false, sos: false}


#Item 2 Log
[Log] Object (e28c8d12-1a95-44e5-9813-dfc2f4bf3bb1, line 502)
code: ""
dose: "1"
name: "Paracetamol"
price: undefined
quantity: "2"
total: NaN
usage: {morning: false, afternoon: false, evening: false, night: false, sos: false}
Object Prototype
```

HTML Code

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Dose</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Usage</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for item in inventory %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.brand }} {{ item.item_name }}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dose", id="dose">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="duration" id="duration">
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="morning" name="morning">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="morning">Morning</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="afternoon" name="afternoon">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="afternoon">Afternoon</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="evening" name="evening">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="evening">Evening</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="night" name="night">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="night">Night</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="sos" name="sos">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="sos">SOS</label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-light bx bx-plus" type="button" id="qty" onclick="addItem({'dose':document.getElementById('dose').value,'quantity':document.getElementById('duration').value,'name':'{{item.item_name}}','code':this.name,'usage':{'morning':document.getElementById('morning').checked,'afternoon':document.getElementById('afternoon').checked,'evening':document.getElementById('evening').checked,'night':document.getElementById('night').checked,'sos':document.getElementById('sos').checked} })"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is the simple JS script that I'm using

```
    function addItem(dataToAdd){
        console.log(dataToAdd);
        dataToAdd['price']=dataToAdd['price'];
        dataToAdd['total']=dataToAdd['price']*dataToAdd['quantity'];
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to show your code to identify the cause. Could be a variable scoping issue.

Comment: I have updated my question with JS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template you have rows like

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="dose", id="dose">
```

It seems that each input does not have its unique id, so when you click the button on any row you get the same result. The solution could be modifying backend part with something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="dose", id="{{ item.somedoseid }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution may be with pure JS only (if it is more convenient or as an example):

```
<button class="btn btn-light bx bx-plus" type="button" id="qty" onclick="
addItem({
'dose':this.parentNode.parentNode.children[1].firstElementChild.value,
'quantity':this.parentNode.parentNode.children[2].firstElementChild.value,
'name':'{{item.item_name}}',
'code':this.name,
'usage':{'morning':this.parentNode.parentNode.children[3].children[0].firstElementChild.checked,
'afternoon':this.parentNode.parentNode.children[3].children[1].firstElementChild.checked,
'evening':this.parentNode.parentNode.children[3].children[2].firstElementChild.checked,
'night':this.parentNode.parentNode.children[3].children[3].firstElementChild.checked,
'sos':this.parentNode.parentNode.children[3].children[4].firstElementChild.checked} })">BtnText</button>
```